# ESP32 esp_netif undefined references during linking

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I have an esp32 project based on the main branch of the esp-idf repository. I am able to get all the way through the comile process up until linking at which point I get the following errors.

```
/Users/###/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20230928/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp-elf/13.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/project_components/libproject_components.a(wifi_manager.c.obj):(.literal.wifi_manager+0x10c): undefined reference to `esp_netif_set_ip_info'
/Users/###/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20230928/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp-elf/13.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/project_components/libproject_components.a(wifi_manager.c.obj): in function `wifi_manager':
/Users/###/src/mytaptrack/button-2-0-firmware/Mytaptrack-EDUC/project_components/src/wifi_manager.c:883:(.text.wifi_manager+0x214): undefined reference to `esp_netif_set_ip_info'
/Users/###/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20230928/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp-elf/13.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp-elf/bin/ld: /Users/###/src/mytaptrack/button-2-0-firmware/Mytaptrack-EDUC/project_components/src/wifi_manager.c:1158:(.text.wifi_manager+0x88d): undefined reference to `esp_netif_set_ip_info'
/Users/###/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20230928/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp-elf/13.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp-elf/bin/ld: /Users/###/src/mytaptrack/button-2-0-firmware/Mytaptrack-EDUC/project_components/src/wifi_manager.c:1216:(.text.wifi_manager+0x95b): undefined reference to `esp_netif_set_ip_info'
/Users/###/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20230928/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp-elf/13.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/esp_wifi/libesp_wifi.a(wifi_default.c.obj):(.literal.wifi_start+0xc): undefined reference to `esp_netif_netstack_buf_free'
/Users/###/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20230928/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp-elf/13.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/esp_wifi/libesp_wifi.a(wifi_default.c.obj):(.literal.wifi_start+0x10): undefined reference to `esp_netif_netstack_buf_ref'
/Users/###/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp-elf/esp-13.2.0_20230928/xtensa-esp-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp-elf/13.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp-elf/bin/ld: esp-idf/esp_wifi/libesp_wifi.a(wifi_default.c.obj):(.literal.esp_netif_create_default_wifi_ap+0x4): undefined reference to `_g_esp_netif_netstack_default_wifi_ap'
```

Comment: You haven't provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your CMakeLists.txt, build config or anything else that would allow us to actually help you. Do pay attention to the [build requirements](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_netif.html#header-file) of the ESP-NETIF module.